extract field data using cut command
i am trying to get m3u8 data from
"https://app-api6.podbbang.com/musicpod-playlists/musicpod77?with=media"
only want this part "https://pod-alive.podbbang.com/podblive/musicpod77/playlist.m3u8?token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
link=$(curl -s 'https://app-api6.podbbang.com/musicpod-playlists/musicpod77?with=media' | grep "source" | cut -d\" -f 3)

echo $link

please help me.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

There are several problems with your command:

You can't grep by source since it's one big string this will bring back the same things as without the grep
-f 3 returns the 3rd field (which is a : between id and musicpod77 at the start of the JSON string) and not the source which is much later in the data
Also, the URL is escaped in the output, so you'd want to replace it

You can use something like:
curl -s 'https://app-api6.podbbang.com/musicpod-playlists/musicpod77?with=media' | cut -d\" -f 32 | sed 's/\\//g'

Or better (to find the source regardless where it is...):
curl -s 'https://app-api6.podbbang.com/musicpod-playlists/musicpod77?with=media' |  grep -oP '(?<="source":")[^"]*' | sed 's/\\//g'

